# How to circular reference keyof in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this following type:

```
type Test = {
    [K in keyof Test]: string
}
```

I want that `K` to be the key of Test. But I get this error: `Type parameter 'K' has a circular constraint`. How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

This type is used as follows:

```
type Settings = {
    [K in keyof Settings]: string
}
type Items<T> = Record<keyof T, any>
function create(settings: Settings, data: Items<Settings>) {
    
}

create({
    name: "tt"
}, {
    name: "aaaa"
})
```

I want the type inference in data parameter in `create`

Comment: Do you want to restrict `data` to have same keys as `Settings`? Something like `function create<T>(settings: T, data: Record<keyof T, any>) {}`

Comment: Yes this is logically just not possible. I think what @AlekseyL. proposes is what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you want `create<S extends {[key: string]: any}>(settings: S, data: Partial<S>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `Settings` as a record of arbitrary keys (using the predefined type `PropertyKey = string | number | symbol`), with `string` values:

```
type Settings = Record<PropertyKey, string>
```

keep `Items` the same

```
type Items<T> = Record<keyof T, any>
```

and add a generic parameter to `create`:

```
function create<S extends Settings>(settings: S, data: Items<S>) {
}
```

The resulting function will accept `data` objects that have the same keys as settings, and throw an error otherwise:

```
create({name: "tt", x: 'x'}, {name: 42, x: true}) // OK

create({name: "tt", x: 'x'}, {name: 42})
// ERROR: Property 'x' is missing in type '{ name: number; }' but required
// in type 'Items<{ name: string; x: string; }>

create({name: "tt", x: 'x'}, {name: 42, x: true, y: 1})
// ERROR: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'y' does
// not exist in type 'Items<{ name: string; x: string; }>'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKAlCAxgPYBOAJgDwAKJRkJoA0hCADRTrAkqoB8AsACghoSFACSwCAFt0FACq9seQqUoBrFkQBmUeewCGyEAOGDtAV2QEkRZFAIkIBqRRhQIADynIymOAg86LwAFOjwSGjoAFyw7GQuBrGSMnIwvACUUADeQgC%20QkKOzlIh2cgG0hCxAEQINeyesQDkns157OWV1VAALABMjbFcFhB5WQD0E1AA8oyFgsUuEGUVVbX1Q1Ct7Z1rPQPjQlNQAKK4uDO4sTR0EAwg221QiJjSr%20g8L-ai0M3ZUH2sWQFmkACN7gBuKB5ZpQMEWYBQJwARwsiCcZG%20UF%202xSsgoAKBHC4PGhTRJ3DQ0LypiKTmWq26G2ADSgFJ2HRyxIGWxGEHYIFiAEYjoITudLtdZmCAFaEJEAG0QUhIBkVUGkBkedkVj3QkAIiG0j3UyCIAHd7GBaPQkBB0IZfNsQHCyEQHYCiEivK8kSgceA-vi5ETmZSyezYpwqagabxmgA6IRAA)

Support for autocomplete on `data` properties can be achieved by adding a generic key parameter, which will allow partial `data` objects:

```
type Items<K extends PropertyKey> = Record<K, any>

function create<S extends Settings, K extends keyof S>(settings: S, data: Items<K> ) {
}

create({name: "tt", x: 'x'}, {name: 42, x: true}) // OK

create({name: "tt", x: 'x'}, {name: 42}) // OK: data can omit properties 

create({name: "tt", x: 'x'}, {name: 42, x: true, y: 1})
// ERROR: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'y' does
// not exist in type 'Items<{ name: string; x: string; }>'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKAlCAxgPYBOAJgDwAKJRkJoA0hCADRTrAkqoB8AsACghoSFACSwCAFt0FRlAgAPKcjKYadCAxDMQvbHkKlKjdgENk%20oUIBmAV2QEkRZFAIkI5qRRiKVEGqYcAg86OwKyqrqUADWLES2sLwAFOjwSGjoAFyw7GTe5rmSMnKMBgCUUADeQgC%20NoIeXlIp1cjm0hC5AEQIPexKuQDkSsN17O2d3VAALABMg7lc9hB1VQD0G1AA8oyNzd4QbR1dvf1LUKPjk6czC%20tQW7uMuQXA5u6WUETSiMBQMC0ehICCYA6eI4nabnYADKBDK5jCY1O65BaXFYQdggXIARnWQmeAFFcLgdrhcjsAEYAK0IAIANv9tOZGVBpOYQD9kIzuehIARELZubFkEQAO5uIFaBiIMEWNRXEDDKBkIhgonbcUA5SIThQFBQUTQYYlWQUapQNEcLg8ADcCNynG4aEddV4wwAdEIgA)